# Replace the unique values in a DataFrame column with their count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a DataFrame such as this:

```
Index Label
0     ABCD
1     EFGH
2     ABCD
3     ABCD
4     EFGH
5     ABCD
6     IJKL
7     IJKL
8     ABCD
9     EFGH
```

So, "ABCD" occurs 5 times, "EFGH" 3 times and "IJKL" twice. I want to count the occurence of each Label and replace the individual labels with their count, to get the following:

```
Index Label
0     5
1     3
2     5
3     5
4     3
5     5
6     2
7     2
8     5
9     3
```

What is the nicest way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['Label'] = df['Label'].map(df['Label'].value_counts())
print (df)
   Label
0      5
1      3
2      5
3      5
4      3
5      5
6      2
7      2
8      5
9      3
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['Label'] = df.groupby('Label')['Label'].transform('size')
print (df)

   Label
0      5
1      3
2      5
3      5
4      3
5      5
6      2
7      2
8      5
9      3
```

Comment: Are you sure? I think always is necessary `size`, and if need exclude `NaN`s need `count` (rarest using)

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
print(df)
      Label
Index      
0      ABCD
1      EFGH
2      ABCD
3      ABCD
4      EFGH
5      ABCD
6      IJKL
7      IJKL
8      ABCD
9      EFGH

df['Label'] = df.groupby('Label').Label.transform('count')
print(df)
       Label
Index       
0          5
1          3
2          5
3          5
4          3
5          5
6          2
7          2
8          5
9          3
```

If your column does not have `NaN`s, `size` and `count` return the same values. Otherwise, `size` includes `NaN`s, so avoid using it.

---

Another way using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

df['Label'] = df.Label.map(Counter(df.Label))
print(df)
       Label
Index       
0          5
1          3
2          5
3          5
4          3
5          5
6          2
7          2
8          5
9          3
```

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor Also, if you are using the groupby solution, don't use `size` as jezrael's solution has.

Comment: I dont understand `Otherwise, size includes NaNs, so avoid using it.` Why avoid? I think both functions are nice - And I think function `count` is the best not used, only if need exclude NaNs explicitly. I think there is no reason for avoid using `size`, because is good if I know I have some NaNs (and I think no NaNs in data - especially if float data).